# "__thread" on Ubuntu

Tags: c, multithreading

- Hi, I m using a C library to program the robot. When reading the 
  code, I encountered the       term "_*thread" that i ve no idea what
  does it means. i tried to search through the project to see whether 
  there are any definitions on "*_thread", but it does not make sense 
  to me. The code below i guess is likely related to my issue.

My question is that from the line of "static __thread Thread* threadData;" and "__thread AssertFramework::Thread* AssertFramework::threadData = 0;", can you guess what “__thread " means? is it a type? a name of special function? the pointer to a thread???

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstring>
...
class AssertFramework
{
public:
  struct Line
  {
    char file[128];
    int line;
    char message[128];
  };

  struct Track
  {
    Line line[16];
    int currentLine;
    bool active;
  };

  struct Thread
  {
    char name[32];
    Track track[2];
  };

  struct Data
  {
    Thread thread[2];
    int currentThread;
  };

  static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  static __thread Thread* threadData;

  int fd;
  Data* data;

  AssertFramework() : fd(-1), data((Data*)MAP_FAILED) {}

  ~AssertFramework()
  {
    if(data != MAP_FAILED)
      munmap(data, sizeof(Data));
    if(fd != -1)
      close(fd);
  }

  bool init(bool reset)
  {
    if(data != MAP_FAILED)
      return true;

    fd = shm_open("/bhuman_assert", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(fd == -1)
      return false;

    if(ftruncate(fd, sizeof(Data)) == -1 ||
       (data = (Data*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(Data), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
    {
      close(fd);
      fd = -1;
      return false;
    }

    if(reset)
      memset(data, 0, sizeof(Data));

    return true;
  }

} assertFramework;

pthread_mutex_t AssertFramework::mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
__thread AssertFramework::Thread* AssertFramework::threadData = 0;
```

Comment: Could be a compiler specific implementation of [Thread Local Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)

Comment: It's a storage class, like `static` or `extern`.

Answer (score 1):

That's gcc specific [Thread-Local Storage](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html). Note that C11 adds `_Thread_local` and C++11 adds `thread_local` as a standard way to support thread-local data.